# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, database

I just installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 but it doesn't work I can't even connect. I see people saying I have to write `pc name \SQLExpress` but it doesn't work, nothing works, I can't even see any servers on here.

[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqZkW.png)

Comment: So ***WHAT EXACTLY*** did you install? From the screenshot, it seems you just plain **DO NOT** have a SQL Server database engine running - no wonder you cannot connect to it !!

Comment: How can I download it ?

I have downloaded Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. and Im trying to connect but I cant. cuz I dont have any database engine and I know how to set it.

Comment: Sorry, Im kinda newbie, so please more details :)

Comment: **Management STudio** is ***ONLY*** the management GUI - it does ***NOT*** contain the actual SQL Server **database engine**! You need to download SQL Server Express **with Tools** to get both - database engine **and** management GUI

Comment: Oh then should I download this one?
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23650&hash=gd1dlWgN2MENbwICU7HZF6IJ8P%2fBcK%2bSksGROLhLKVvASK20kopFqYDj6noUKD45hd4hsFdwtNEnJ35Jy7j9RQ%3d%3d

Comment: If in installation you are chosing default instance ,try to connect with .\SQLEXPRESS ,if you select Named instance try  .\[name how you are choose]

Comment: @MoemenWalid: yes - the **Express with Tools** version is what you're looking for